# How to get all combinations of an array column in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Suppose I have an array column `group_ids`

```
+-------+----------+
|user_id|group_ids |
+-------+----------+
|1      |[5, 8]    |
|3      |[1, 2, 3] |
|2      |[1, 4]    |
+-------+----------+
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- user_id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- group_ids: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

I want to get all combinations of pairs:

```
+-------+------------------------+
|user_id|group_ids               |
+-------+------------------------+
|1      |[[5, 8]]                |
|3      |[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]|
|2      |[[1, 4]]                |
+-------+------------------------+
```

So far I created the easiest solution with UDF:

```
spark.udf.register("permutate", udf((xs: Seq[Int]) => xs.combinations(2).toSeq))

dataset.withColumn("group_ids", expr("permutate(group_ids)"))
```

What I'm looking for is something that implemented via Spark Built-in functions. Is there a way to implement the same code without UDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some higher order functions can do the trick. Requires Spark >= 2.4.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "group_ids", 
    expr("""
        filter(
            transform(
                flatten(
                    transform(
                        group_ids, 
                        x -> arrays_zip(
                            array_repeat(x, size(group_ids)), 
                            group_ids
                        )
                    )
                ), 
                x -> array(x['0'], x['group_ids'])
            ), 
            x -> x[0] < x[1]
        )
    """)
)


df2.show(false)
+-------+------------------------+
|user_id|group_ids               |
+-------+------------------------+
|1      |[[5, 8]]                |
|3      |[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]|
|2      |[[1, 4]]                |
+-------+------------------------+
```

Comment: PySpark approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73726375/pair-combinations-of-array-column-in-pyspark/73726652

Answer (score 1):

Based on `explode` and `joins` solution

```
val exploded = df.select(col("user_id"), explode(col("group_ids")).as("e"))

// to have combinations
val joined1 = exploded.as("t1")
                      .join(exploded.as("t2"), Seq("user_id"), "outer")
                      .select(col("user_id"), col("t1.e").as("e1"), col("t2.e").as("e2"))

// to filter out redundant combinations
val joined2 = joined1.as("t1")
                     .join(joined1.as("t2"), $"t1.user_id" === $"t2.user_id" && $"t1.e1" === $"t2.e2" && $"t1.e2"=== $"t2.e1")
                     .where("t1.e1 < t2.e1")
                     .select("t1.*")

// group into array
val result = joined2.groupBy("user_id")
                    .agg(collect_set(struct("e1", "e2")).as("group_ids"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the max size of the column `group_ids`. Then, using combinations on the range `(1 - maxSize)` with `when` expressions to create the sub arrays combinations from the original array, and finaly filter the null elements from the resulting array:

```
val maxSize = df.select(max(size($"group_ids"))).first.getAs[Int](0)

val newCol = (1 to maxSize).combinations(2)
  .map(c =>
    when(
      size($"group_ids") >= c(1),
      array(element_at($"group_ids", c(0)), element_at($"group_ids", c(1)))
    )
  ).toSeq

df.withColumn("group_ids", array(newCol: _*))
  .withColumn("group_ids", expr("filter(group_ids, x -> x is not null)"))
  .show(false)

//+-------+------------------------+
//|user_id|group_ids               |
//+-------+------------------------+
//|1      |[[5, 8]]                |
//|3      |[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]|
//|2      |[[1, 4]]                |
//+-------+------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be pretty clear and efficient, its in pyspark but shouldn't be hard to translate

```
df.select("user_id", F.array_sort("group_ids").alias("group_ids")).select(
    # In case of only 2 numbers, try to optimize and skip the transforms
    F.when(F.size("group_ids") == 2, F.array(F.col("group_ids")))
    .otherwise(
        F.flatten(
            F.transform(
                "group_ids",
                lambda id, index: F.transform(
                    F.slice("group_ids", index + 2, F.size("group_ids") - 1),
                    lambda id2: F.array(id, id2),
                ),
            )
        )
    )
    .alias("pairs")
)
```