# Pair combinations of array column values in PySpark

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, combinations

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66716553/how-to-get-all-combinations-of-an-array-column-in-spark) (Scala), but I need combinations in PySpark (pair combinations of array column).

Example input:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [([0, 1],),
     ([2, 3, 4],),
     ([5, 6, 7, 8],)],
    ['array_col'])
```

Expected output:

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
|array_col   |out                                             |
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
|[0, 1]      |[[0, 1]]                                        |
|[2, 3, 4]   |[[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]                        |
|[5, 6, 7, 8]|[[5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [6, 7], [6, 8], [7, 8]]|
+------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`pandas_udf`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) is an efficient and concise approach in PySpark.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

@F.pandas_udf('array<array<int>>')
def pudf(c: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return c.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))


df = df.withColumn('out', pudf('array_col'))
df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------+------------------------------------------------+
# |array_col   |out                                             |
# +------------+------------------------------------------------+
# |[0, 1]      |[[0, 1]]                                        |
# |[2, 3, 4]   |[[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]                        |
# |[5, 6, 7, 8]|[[5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [6, 7], [6, 8], [7, 8]]|
# +------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Note: in some systems, instead of `'array<array<int>>'` you may need to provide types from `pyspark.sql.types`, e.g. `ArrayType(ArrayType(IntegerType()))`.

Comment: How efficient is the Pandas UDF version compared to the native spark version? From a code maintenance perspective, I find the UDF code to be much easier to understand and more preferrable.

Answer (score 6):

**Native Spark** approach. I've translated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66716553/how-to-get-all-combinations-of-an-array-column-in-spark#66719564) to PySpark.

Python 3.8+ (walrus `:=` operator for `"array_col"` which is repeated several times in this script):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "out",
    F.filter(
        F.transform(
            F.flatten(F.transform(
                c:="array_col",
                lambda x: F.arrays_zip(F.array_repeat(x, F.size(c)), c)
            )),
            lambda x: F.array(x["0"], x[c])
        ),
        lambda x: x[0] < x[1]
    )
)
df.show(truncate=0)
# +------------+------------------------------------------------+
# |array_col   |out                                             |
# +------------+------------------------------------------------+
# |[0, 1]      |[[0, 1]]                                        |
# |[2, 3, 4]   |[[2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]                        |
# |[5, 6, 7, 8]|[[5, 6], [5, 7], [5, 8], [6, 7], [6, 8], [7, 8]]|
# +------------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Alternative without walrus operator:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "out",
    F.filter(
        F.transform(
            F.flatten(F.transform(
                "array_col",
                lambda x: F.arrays_zip(F.array_repeat(x, F.size("array_col")), "array_col")
            )),
            lambda x: F.array(x["0"], x["array_col"])
        ),
        lambda x: x[0] < x[1]
    )
)
```

Alternative for Spark 2.4+

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn(
    "out",
    F.expr("""
        filter(
            transform(
                flatten(transform(
                    array_col,
                    x -> arrays_zip(array_repeat(x, size(array_col)), array_col)
                )),
                x -> array(x["0"], x["array_col"])
            ),
            x -> x[0] < x[1]
        )
    """)
)
```