# How to join dataframe on itself creating all combinations inside groups

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, combinations

Some mock data:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'date': {0: Timestamp('2021-08-01 '),
  1: Timestamp('2022-08-01 '),
  2: Timestamp('2021-08-02 '),
  3: Timestamp('2021-08-01 '),
  4: Timestamp('2022-08-01 '),
  5: Timestamp('2022-08-01 '),
  6: Timestamp('2022-08-01 ')                   },
 'product_nr': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7},
 'Category': {0:  'Cars', 1: 'Cars', 2: 'Cats', 3: 'Dogs', 4: 'Dogs', 5: 'Cats', 6 :'Cats'},
 'price': {0: '34',
  1: '24',
  2: '244',
  3: '284',
  4: '274',
  5: '354',
  6 : '250'}} )
```

How do I do an inner join on the same dataframe with a specific condition? I want to compare prices between rows that are the same category.
Desired output:

```py
pd.DataFrame({
 'product_nr': {0: 1,  1: 3,  2: 5, 3: 7, 4:7},
 'Category': {0:  'Cars',  1: 'Cats', 2: 'Dogs', 3:'Cats', 4:'Cats'},
 'price': {0: '34',
  1: '244',
  2: '274',
  3: '250',
  4: '250'},
 'product_to_be_compared' : {0: 2,  1: 6,  2: 4, 3:3 , 4:6}
} )
```

I.e., I want to do an inner join / cross join (not sure what's most suitable). I have a large dataframe and I want to pair rows together if they are the same category and date. Ideally, I would prefer to remove duplicated pairs, meaning my desired output would be 4 rows.

Comment: Do you always have 2 values per category or can you have more?

Comment: No, I have more than 2 values per category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your questions I know you're familiar with PySpark. This is how it could be done using PySpark dataframes. Even though it uses external `itertools` library, it should perform well, because that part resides inside a [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) which is vectorized for performance.

Input df:

```py
import pandas as pd

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': {
        0: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-01'),
        1: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-01'),
        2: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-02'),
        3: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-03'),
        4: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-03'),
        5: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-02'),
        6: pd.Timestamp('2021-08-02')
    },
    'product_nr': {0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4', 4: '5', 5: '6', 6: '7'},
    'Category': {0:  'Cars', 1: 'Cars', 2: 'Cats', 3: 'Dogs', 4: 'Dogs', 5: 'Cats', 6 :'Cats'},
    'price': {
        0: '34',
        1: '24',
        2: '244',
        3: '284',
        4: '274',
        5: '354',
        6 : '250'
    }
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
```

Script:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import combinations

@F.pandas_udf('array<array<string>>')
def arr_combinations(c: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return c.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))

df2 = df.groupBy('Category', 'date').agg(F.collect_list('product_nr').alias('ps'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('ps', F.explode(arr_combinations('ps')))
df2 = df2.select(
    'Category', 'date',
    F.col('ps')[0].alias('product_nr'),
    F.col('ps')[1].alias('product_to_be_compared')
)
df3 = df.join(df2, ['product_nr', 'Category', 'date'])

df3.show()
# +----------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------------------+
# |product_nr|Category|               date|price|product_to_be_compared|
# +----------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------------------+
# |         3|    Cats|2021-08-02 00:00:00|  244|                     7|
# |         3|    Cats|2021-08-02 00:00:00|  244|                     6|
# |         1|    Cars|2021-08-01 00:00:00|   34|                     2|
# |         6|    Cats|2021-08-02 00:00:00|  354|                     7|
# |         4|    Dogs|2021-08-03 00:00:00|  284|                     5|
# +----------+--------+-------------------+-----+----------------------+
```

---

If you want to compare prices directly in this table, use the following:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from itertools import combinations

@F.pandas_udf('array<array<array<string>>>')
def arr_combinations(c: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return c.apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2)))

df2 = df.groupBy('Category', 'date').agg(F.collect_list(F.array('product_nr', 'price')).alias('ps'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('ps', F.explode(arr_combinations('ps')))
df2 = df2.select(
    F.col('ps')[0][0].alias('product_nr'),
    'Category',
    'date',
    F.col('ps')[0][1].alias('product_price'),
    F.col('ps')[1][0].alias('product_to_be_compared'),
    F.col('ps')[1][1].alias('product_to_be_compared_price'),
)
df2.show()
# +----------+--------+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
# |product_nr|Category|               date|product_price|product_to_be_compared|product_to_be_compared_price|
# +----------+--------+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
# |         1|    Cars|2021-08-01 00:00:00|           34|                     2|                          24|
# |         3|    Cats|2021-08-02 00:00:00|          244|                     6|                         354|
# |         3|    Cats|2021-08-02 00:00:00|          244|                     7|                         250|
# |         6|    Cats|2021-08-02 00:00:00|          354|                     7|                         250|
# |         4|    Dogs|2021-08-03 00:00:00|          284|                     5|                         274|
# +----------+--------+-------------------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: If it's a string, change the `'array<array<bigint>>'` to `'array<array<string>>'`

Comment: Also, if you think you can't use pandas_udf, you can do that part with native Spark, but you will have to write more complex code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73726375/pair-combinations-of-array-column-in-pyspark#73726652

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248171/discussion-between-aria-f-and-zygd).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have two products per category, you can invert the values per group:

```
df['product_to_be_compared'] = (df.groupby('Category')['product_nr']
                                  .transform(lambda s: s[::-1].values)
                               )
```

output:

```
        date  product_nr Category price  product_to_be_compared
0 2021-08-01           1     Cars    34                       2
1 2022-08-01           2     Cars    24                       1
2 2021-08-02           3     Cats   244                       6
3 2021-08-01           4     Dogs   284                       5
4 2022-08-01           5     Dogs   274                       4
5 2022-08-01           6     Cats   354                       3
```

To swap several columns:

```
df[['prod2', 'price2']] = (df.groupby('Category')['product_nr', 'price']
                             .transform(lambda s: s[::-1].values)
                           )
```

output:

```
        date  product_nr Category price  prod2 price2
0 2021-08-01           1     Cars    34      2     24
1 2022-08-01           2     Cars    24      1     34
2 2021-08-02           3     Cats   244      6    354
3 2021-08-01           4     Dogs   284      5    274
4 2022-08-01           5     Dogs   274      4    284
5 2022-08-01           6     Cats   354      3    244
```

##### update: linking to another value in the same group while dropping duplicates

```
m = df.groupby('Category').cumcount().eq(1)
mapper = df[m].set_index('Category')['product_nr']
df[~m].assign(product_to_be_compared=lambda d: d['Category'].map(mapper))
```

output:

```
        date  product_nr Category price  product_to_be_compared
0 2021-08-01           1     Cars    34                       2
2 2021-08-02           3     Cats   244                       6
3 2021-08-01           4     Dogs   284                       5
6 2022-08-02           7     Cats   250                       6
```

Comment: @Aria can you then update your example?

Comment: @Aria the logic is still unclear (why do you keep row 1?), check the update and let me know the exact logic if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: As said, the logic is inconsistent, you have 3 categories with 3+2+2 items, and you end up with 3+1+1, is this expected? "*I have X, I want Y*" is not a description of the logic ;)

Comment: Can you fix the output? and explicit the logic?

Comment: OK, so if you have 4 rows, you'd have 5 combinations?