# Get count of items occurring together in PySpark

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe that has 10000s of rows. The columns are (1) number of items occurring together as string and (2) the frequency of occurrence. I want to get how many times each items occurs with the rest of the items. I have sample data below.

```
pd.DataFrame({'items':['[a,b,c]','[c,d,e]', '[a,e]','[a,b,e]','[b,c]', '[c,d,e,b]'],'freq':[10, 16,7,2,6,5]})
```

The expected output is something like below.

```
[(a, b), 12], [(a, c), 10], [(c, d), 21], etc
```

Comment: could you please add the expected output?

Comment: Added a possible expected output. Thanks!

Comment: how did you calculate the results? I would expect (a,c) -> 10 and (c,d) -> 21

Comment: You are right. I was looking at slightly different data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726652/2129801) all possible combinations of two letters can be calculated. Then the result is exploded, grouped and summed up:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("items_array", F.expr('split(regexp_replace(items, "[\\\\[\\\\]]", ""), ",")', )) \
  .withColumn(
    "out",
    F.expr("""
        filter(
            transform(
                flatten(transform(
                    items_array,
                    x -> arrays_zip(array_repeat(x, size(items_array)), items_array)
                )),
                x -> array(x["0"], x["items_array"])
            ),
            x -> x[0] < x[1]
        )
    """)
  ) \
  .withColumn("out", F.explode("out")) \
  .groupBy("out") \
  .agg(F.sum("freq")) \
  .orderBy("out") \
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+
|   out|sum(freq)|
+------+---------+
|[a, b]|       12|
|[a, c]|       10|
|[a, e]|        9|
|[b, c]|       21|
|[b, d]|        5|
|[b, e]|        7|
|[c, d]|       21|
|[c, e]|       21|
|[d, e]|       21|
+------+---------+
```