# Spark Transitive Equality Mapping Usecase

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have the following use case where based on the Comp_Key Column, we will have multiple Comp_Name's and their associated Comp_Value's and ID column, which is unique for a given Comp_Name - Comp_Value combination.

The task is to reassign the generated ID column based on the combination of the Comp_value across the Comp_Names, where the transitive equality (if A=B and B=C, then A=c) rule applies.

For ex, Comp_value '123' is assigned to multiple Comp_Name's - abc.com/Collin.com/Boyd.com/clad.com. In the same way, Comp_value '356' is assigned to both Comp_Name's - MB.com and Collin.com. so we need to treat all of these comp_names as a single entity and need to assign the same ID value and can take any of the ID's of the three Comp_Names and so can assign ID = 1.

Similarly, Comp_value = 435 has matching Comp_Names - miro.com and xyz.com, so we can treat these two comp_names as same and assign any of the ID values and take 7 for both of these.

Even though the Comp_Names Denton.com/Insta.com have the same Comp_key = A, we dont consider these in the above set, as they don't have any matching Comp_values w.r.t any of the above sets.

```
|Comp_KEY| Comp_NAME  | Comp_Value | ID|
|--------|------------|------------|---|
|  A     | abc.com    |  123       | 1 |
|  A     | abc.com    |            | 1 |
|  A     | MB inc     |  356       | 2 |
|  A     | Collin.com |  123       | 3 |
|  A     | Collin.com |  356       | 3 |
|  A     | Boyd.com   |  123       | 4 |
|  A     | Boyd.com   |  790       | 4 |
|  A     | clad.com   |  123       | 5 |
|  A     | clad.com   |  2324      | 5 |
|  A     | Denton.com |  555       | 6 |
|  A     | Denton.com |  666       | 6 |
|  A     | Micro.com  |  435       | 7 |
|  A     | Micro.com  |  987       | 7 |
|  A     | XYZ.com    |  435       | 8 |
|  A     | XYZ.com    |  334       | 8 |
|  A     | Insta.com  |  777       | 9 |
|--------|------------|------------|---|
```

The expected output with the new ID column will be..

```
|Comp_KEY| Comp_NAME  | Comp_Value | ID|
|--------|------------|------------|---|
|  A     | abc.com    |  123       | 1 |
|  A     | abc.com    |            | 1 |
|  A     | MB inc     |  356       | 1 |
|  A     | Collin.com |  123       | 1 |
|  A     | Collin.com |  356       | 1 |
|  A     | Boyd.com   |  123       | 1 |
|  A     | Boyd.com   |  790       | 1 |
|  A     | clad.com   |  123       | 1 |
|  A     | clad.com   |  2324      | 1 |
|  A     | Denton.com |  555       | 6 |
|  A     | Denton.com |  666       | 6 |
|  A     | Micro.com  |  435       | 7 |
|  A     | Micro.com  |  987       | 7 |
|  A     | XYZ.com    |  435       | 7 |
|  A     | XYZ.com    |  334       | 7 |
|  A     | Insta.com  |  777       | 9 |
|--------|------------|------------|---|
```

any help is appreciated. Thank You -^-.

Answer (score 0):

Using [graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html) we can calculate the transitive dependencies. If the `Comp_NAMES` are regarded as vertices and the connections between them (in the column `Comp_Value`) are regarded as edges of a [network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory), the groups of companies are the [connected components](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#connected-components) of this network.

#### 1. Prepare the graphframe-lib and the Spark session

```python
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os

os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = (
    "--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.2-spark3.0-s_2.12 pyspark-shell"
)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("checkpoints")
```

#### 2. Prepare the data

```python
data = [
    ['abc.com',123],
    ['abc.com',None],
    ['MB inc',356],
    ['Collin.com',123],
    ['Collin.com',356],
    ['Boyd.com',123],
    ['Boyd.com',790],
    ['clad.com',123],
    ['clad.com',2324],
    ['Denton.com',555],
    ['Denton.com',666],
    ['Micro.com',435],
    ['Micro.com',987],
    ['XYZ.com',435],
    ['XYZ.com',334],
    ['Insta.com',777]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['Comp_NAME','Comp_Value'])
```

#### 3. Get the vertices

```pythion
vertices = df.select('Comp_NAME').distinct().withColumnRenamed('Comp_NAME', 'id')
```

#### 4. Get the edges

```python
edges = df.groupBy('Comp_Value').agg(F.collect_list('Comp_NAME').alias('edges')) \
    .filter(F.size('edges')>= 2) \
    .withColumn(
    "edges",
        F.expr("""
            filter(
                transform(
                    flatten(transform(
                        edges,
                        x -> arrays_zip(array_repeat(x, size(edges)), edges)
                    )),
                    x -> array(x["0"], x["edges"])
                ),
                x -> x[0] < x[1]
            )
        """)
    ) \
    .withColumn("edges", F.explode("edges")) \
    .withColumn('src', F.col('edges')[0]) \
    .withColumn('dst', F.col('edges')[1])
```

If there are more than two companies connected with a single id, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726652) is used to get all possible pairs of connected companies for this id.

#### 5. Get the connected components of the graph

```python
from graphframes import *

g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
cc = g.connectedComponents()

cc.orderBy('component').show()
```

Output:

```
+----------+-------------+
|        id|    component|
+----------+-------------+
| Micro.com|  17179869184|
|   XYZ.com|  17179869184|
|  Boyd.com| 163208757248|
|    MB inc| 163208757248|
|   abc.com| 163208757248|
|  clad.com| 163208757248|
|Collin.com| 163208757248|
|Denton.com| 867583393792|
| Insta.com|1571958030336|
+----------+-------------+
```

If required this result can now be joined with the original input dataframe.

Comment: Hello @werner. Thank you for taking time to provider me an answer. Upon further checking into my data, there is a possibility of having the edges group list size >2 and for that data, the logic is not working. 
I have edited my question accordingly and can you please take a look, as the generated component value is not same for a given set.
Thank again for your help.

Comment: @marc I think it should work now