# Generate all possible combination of column elements which share same date (columns) in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a data frame in pyspark

```
data = [
    ("2023-09-03", "NA", "US", 1, "us1"),
    ("2023-09-03", "NA", "US", 1, "us2"),
    ("2023-09-03", "NA", "MX", 1, "mx1"),
    ("2023-09-03", "NA","CA", 2, "ca1"),
    ("2023-09-03", "NA","CA", 2, "ca2")
]

columns = ["date", "region" ,"country", "id", "person"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns).drop("country")
df.display()
```

> ```
> date  region  id  person
> 2023-09-03    NA  1   us1
> 2023-09-03    NA  1   us2
> 2023-09-03    NA  1   mx1
> 2023-09-03    NA  2   ca1
> 2023-09-03    NA  2   ca2
> ```

I am trying to list all person that shares the same columns i.e. date, region, and id. I am expecting a result like

> ```
> id    date    region  person_x    person_y
> 1 2023-09-03  NA  us1 us2
> 1 2023-09-03  NA  us1 mx1
> 1 2023-09-03  NA  us2 us1
> 1 2023-09-03  NA  us2 mx1
> 1 2023-09-03  NA  mx1 us1
> 1 2023-09-03  NA  mx1 us2
> 2 2023-09-03  NA  ca1 ca2
> 2 2023-09-03  NA  ca2 ca1
> ```

I have tried it with a self-join but is there an efficient solution for this? here what I've tried

```
join_cols = ["id", "date", "region"]
df_x = df.select(join_cols + ["person"]).withColumnRenamed("person", "person_x")
df_y = df.select(join_cols + ["person"]).withColumnRenamed("person", "person_y")

df_mix = df_x.join(df_y, on=join_cols, how="inner").filter("person_x != person_y")
df_mix.display()
```

Comment: `join` seems a fairly reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `group by` instead of a `join`:

**Step 1**: Group the data by `join_cols` and use [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#collect_list) as aggregation function (column `persons` in the code below).

**Step 2**: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726652/2129801) to get all permutations of the `persons` array (-> `combinations`).

**Step 3**: Explode the `combinations` column (-> `pairs`)

**Step 4**: Split the pairs into two columns `person_x` and `person_y`.

```python
df.groupBy(join_cols).agg(F.collect_list('person').alias('persons')) \
    .withColumn(
        "combinations",
        F.filter(
            F.transform(
                F.flatten(F.transform(
                    c:="persons",
                    lambda x: F.arrays_zip(F.array_repeat(x, F.size(c)), c)
                )),
                lambda x: F.array(x["0"], x[c])
            ),
            lambda x: x[0] != x[1]
        )
        )\
    .withColumn('pairs', F.explode('combinations')) \
    .withColumn('person_x', F.col('pairs')[0]) \
    .withColumn('person_y', F.col('pairs')[1]) \
    .drop('persons', 'combinations', 'pairs') \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+------+--------+--------+
|id |date      |region|person_x|person_y|
+---+----------+------+--------+--------+
|1  |2023-09-03|NA    |us1     |us2     |
|1  |2023-09-03|NA    |us1     |mx1     |
|1  |2023-09-03|NA    |us2     |us1     |
|1  |2023-09-03|NA    |us2     |mx1     |
|1  |2023-09-03|NA    |mx1     |us1     |
|1  |2023-09-03|NA    |mx1     |us2     |
|2  |2023-09-03|NA    |ca1     |ca2     |
|2  |2023-09-03|NA    |ca2     |ca1     |
+---+----------+------+--------+--------+
```