# Find events between 30 and 365 days over a partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have DF which includes patient ids and dates said patients received a medical procedure.
I need to filter the DF to only include patients that underwent the procedure at least twice, with the two procedures occurring between 30 and 365 days apart. I only need to retain the patient ID and the first procedure that meets the time range criteria.

The original DF:

| Pat_ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1-march-18 |
| A | 15-march-18 |
| B | 1-april-19 |
| B | 4-april-19 |
| B | 7-april-19 |
| B | 3-june-19 |

and the filtered DF:

| Pat_ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| B | 7-april-19 |

This is the code that I have tried...to flag the dates of interest. It works, but it's not very efficient. Is there a better solution?

```
w=Window.partitionBy("Pat_ID").orderBy(col("date"))
for i in range(1, 366): 
    df = df.withColumn(f"daysbetween_{i}", when ((datediff((F.lead(F.col('dx_date'), i).over(w)), "dx_date").between(30, 365)),1).otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: Added in using range join conditions*

My overall approach to doing this would be:

1. Join your table to itself by patient id and [range join conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/optimizations/range-join)
2. Calculate the pairwise date difference of each row
3. Group By patient id and aggregate for earliest date

**However, the main problem of this approach is you could run out of memory, depending on your dataset**;
as you can potentially generate `N^2` rows for `N` procedures of each patient.
I've added filters to generate only valid date pairs (within the 30-365 days range),
but it is *still possible to run out of memory* if your dataset is truly large.

---

**Here is my approach:**

First, the mock dataset

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("A", datetime(2018,3,1))
    ,("A", datetime(2018,3,15))
    ,("B", datetime(2019,4,1))
    ,("B", datetime(2019,4,4))
    ,("B", datetime(2019,4,7))
    ,("B", datetime(2019,6,3))
    ,("C", datetime(2018,1,1))
    ,("D", datetime(2018,1,1))
    ,("D", datetime(2018,3,1))
    ,("D", datetime(2020,1,1))
  ]
  ,schema="patient_id string, procedure_date date"
)

df.show()
```

```
+----------+--------------+
|patient_id|procedure_date|
+----------+--------------+
|         A|    2018-03-01|
|         A|    2018-03-15|
|         B|    2019-04-01|
|         B|    2019-04-04|
|         B|    2019-04-07|
|         B|    2019-06-03|
|         C|    2018-01-01|
|         D|    2018-01-01|
|         D|    2018-03-01|
|         D|    2020-01-01|
+----------+--------------+
```

Next, I create the DataFrame `filter_df` to filter for potential patients based on maximum range.
This will filter out:

- Patients with less than 2 procedures
- Patients with two furthest procedures less than 30 days apart

I cannot use `between(30,365)` or `max_range <= 365`
because even if the max-min range is above the 365 days limit,
there can possibly be a date pair with difference less than 365 days between the min-max pair.
However, the opposite is not true. If max-min range is below 30 days,
there cannot be another date pair with range greater than 30 days.

```py
filter_df = df.groupBy("patient_id")\
  .agg(
     F.min("procedure_date").alias("first_date")
    ,F.max("procedure_date").alias("latest_date")
  )\
  .withColumn("max_range", F.date_diff("latest_date", "first_date"))\
  .filter(F.col("max_range") >= 30)

filter_df.show()
```

```
+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
|patient_id|first_date|latest_date|max_range|
+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
|         B|2019-04-01| 2019-06-03|       63|
|         D|2018-01-01| 2020-01-01|      730|
+----------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Applying the filter with inner join:

```py
df = df.join(
  filter_df.select("patient_id")
  ,on="patient_id"
  ,how="inner"
)

df.show()
```

```
+----------+--------------+
|patient_id|procedure_date|
+----------+--------------+
|         B|    2019-04-01|
|         B|    2019-04-04|
|         B|    2019-04-07|
|         B|    2019-06-03|
|         D|    2018-01-01|
|         D|    2018-03-01|
|         D|    2020-01-01|
+----------+--------------+
```

Then I join this filtered result with itself by patient id and using
[range join conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/optimizations/range-join)
*(basically, adding the `date_diff().between()` condition to the `join(on=...)` parameter)*.
For this, I have to rename both patient id and dates column to differentiate them for spark.

This gives me all the valid date-pairs, for all patients.

Using range join conditions, I avoided the quadratic behavior of generating `4^2 + 3^2 = 25` rows.
Instead I only get the 4 valid date pairs within my date range (30, 365) days inclusive.

Whether you use `F.date_diff("date_b", "date_a")` or `F.date_diff("date_a", "date_b")`
doesn't really matter - pair-wise difference is symmetric and you will get the same results anyway. Negative results also do not matter for the same reasons.

```py
df = df\
  .withColumnRenamed("patient_id", "id_a")\
  .withColumnRenamed("procedure_date", "date_a")\
  .join(
    df\
      .withColumnRenamed("patient_id", "id_b")\
      .withColumnRenamed("procedure_date", "date_b")
    ,on=[
      F.col("id_a") == F.col("id_b")
      ,F.date_diff("date_b", "date_a").between(30, 365)
    ]
    ,how="inner"
  )\
  .withColumn("date_diff", F.date_diff("date_b", "date_a"))

df.show()
```

```
+----+----------+----+----------+---------+
|id_a|    date_a|id_b|    date_b|date_diff|
+----+----------+----+----------+---------+
|   B|2019-04-01|   B|2019-06-03|       63|
|   B|2019-04-04|   B|2019-06-03|       60|
|   B|2019-04-07|   B|2019-06-03|       57|
|   D|2018-01-01|   D|2018-03-01|       59|
+----+----------+----+----------+---------+
```

Then I group by patient id, and select `min("date_a")` to get the *first procedure* that matches this criteria.

But I noticed that my code found Patient B's `1 April 2019` to be the answer, instead of your example `7 April 2019` result.

Depending on what you mean by "first" you will have to change the last code block to get your answer. (I simply define "first" as the chronological first date)

```py
df = df\
  .groupBy("id_a")\
  .agg(F.min("date_a").alias("procedure_date"))\
  .select(
    F.col("id_a").alias("patient_id")
    ,"procedure_date"
  )

df.show()
```

```
+----------+--------------+
|patient_id|procedure_date|
+----------+--------------+
|         B|    2019-04-01|
|         D|    2018-01-01|
+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Good explanation and test data (+1)

Answer (score 1):

An approach using the built-in Spark functions without joins (for performance reasons):

1. Group the data by `patient_id` and [collect all dates into a list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list.html).
2. For each list of dates generate all possible pairs of dates using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726652/2129801).
3. [Filter out](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) the pairs of dates that do not meet the criteria to be longer than 30 days and shorter than 365 days.
4. [Sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sort_array.html) the remaining pairs so that the pair with the smallest start date is the first element of the list.
5. The first date of the first pair is the expected date.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = ...

df.groupBy("patient_id").agg(F.collect_list("procedure_date")
                             .alias("procedure_dates"))\
  .withColumn("procedure_dates",
    F.filter(
      F.transform(
        F.flatten(F.transform(
                c:="procedure_dates",
                lambda x: F.arrays_zip(F.array_repeat(x, F.size(c)), c)
        )),
        lambda x: F.array(x["0"], x[c])
      ),
      lambda x: x[0] < x[1]
    ))\
  .withColumn("procedure_dates", F.filter("procedure_dates", 
       lambda col: F.datediff(col[1], col[0]).between(30, 365))) \ 
 .withColumn("procedure_dates", F.sort_array("procedure_dates")) \
  .withColumn("result", F.col("procedure_dates")[0][0]) \
  .drop("procedure_dates") \
  .show()
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+
|patient_id|    result|
+----------+----------+
|         A|      null|
|         B|2019-04-01|
+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Huh, so that's how you generate pairwise arrays in native spark. From a maintenance perspective, I would prefer the [UDF version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73726376/5675094), so long as the performance is comparable.

Comment: Minor corrections: I understand the date range is supposed to be (30, 365) inclusive - so the final filter can be simply: `lambda col: F.datediff(col[1], col[0]).between(30, 365))`. And I would also add a `dropna` to the end to remove patients without matching cases as well.

Comment: @mimocha Thanks for the hint with `between`! And about the udf: I agree that the code for the pairs is not the most maintainable!